# Create view based on hierarchy / used of CTE

Tags: sql, t-sql

Is it possible to create a view based on hierarchy / cte ?

I've seen an example on how to generate a resultset based on the link [recursive query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx).
I've attached the ddl and the statement.

Thank you,
Elmer

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[XHR_PERSON](
[PERSON_ID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[LAST_NAME] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
[FIRST_NAME] [varchar](100)
,EFFECTIVE_START_DATE Date
,EFFECTIVE_END_DATE Date)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[XHR_EMPLOYMENT](
[PERSON_ID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[EMPLOYEE_NUMBER] [varchar](100) NULL,
[SUPERVISOR_ID] [bigint] NULL
,EFFECTIVE_START_DATE Date
,EFFECTIVE_END_DATE Date)

insert into XHR_PERSON 
select 1, 'SMY', null, '1990-01-01','9999-12-31' UNION ALL 
select 2, 'JSB',null, '1990-01-01','9999-12-31' union all
select 3, 'LFG',null, '1990-01-01','9999-12-31' union all
select 4, 'Elmer',null, '1990-01-01','9999-12-31' union all
select 5, 'Jon',null, '1990-01-01','9999-12-31' union all
select 6, 'Anne',null, '1990-01-01','9999-12-31' union all
select 7, 'Teddy',null, '1990-01-01','9999-12-31' union all
select 8, 'Alex',null , '1990-01-01','9999-12-31'union all
select 9, 'Jeff',null, '1990-01-01','9999-12-31'
update XHR_PERSON set first_name = 'A'

insert into XHR_EMPLOYMENT
select 1, '111',null, '1990-01-01','9999-12-31' UNION ALL 
select 2, '222',1, '1990-01-01','9999-12-31' union all
select 3, '333',1, '1990-01-01','9999-12-31' union all
select 4, '444',2, '1990-01-01','9999-12-31' union all
select 5, '555',2, '1990-01-01','9999-12-31' union all
select 6, '666',4, '1990-01-01','9999-12-31' union all
select 7, '777',3, '1990-01-01','9999-12-31' union all
select 8, '888',3, '1990-01-01','9999-12-31' union all
select 9, '999',8, '1990-01-01','9999-12-31'


CREATE VIEW dbo.HR_DIRECTREPORTSV as 
WITH xxDirectReports (Supervisor_id, Person_id, Employee_number, Employee_name, Supervisor_Empno, Supervisor_Name, Level1)

AS
(
SELECT hre.Supervisor_id
    ,hre.Person_id
    ,hre.Employee_number
    ,hrp.last_name+', '+hrp.first_name  Employee_Name
    ,hrpx.employee_number       Supervisor_Empno
    ,hrpx.fullname          Supervisor_Name
    ,0 AS Level1
FROM dbo.xhr_employment AS hre left join (select hrp1.person_id,hre1.employee_number                                                    ,(hrp1.last_name+', '+hrp1.first_name) as fullname
                                           from dbo.xHR_PERSON hrp1
                                                ,dbo.xhr_employment hre1
                                           where hrp1.person_id = hre1.person_id
                                           AND   getdate() between hrp1.effective_start_date 
                                                            and    hrp1.effective_end_date
                                        ) hrpx on hre.supervisor_id = hrpx.person_id
    ,dbo.xHR_PERSON     AS hrp 
WHERE hre.person_id = hrp.person_id 
AND   GETDATE() between hrp.effective_start_date and hrp.effective_end_date
AND   GETDATE() between hrp.effective_start_date and hrp.effective_end_date
--AND   hrpx.person_id = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT   hre.Supervisor_id
        ,hre.Person_id
        ,hre.Employee_number
        ,hrp.last_name+', '+hrp.first_name  Employee_Name
        ,hrpx.employee_number               Supervisor_Empno
        ,hrpx.fullname                      Supervisor_Name
        ,Level1+1
FROM dbo.xhr_employment AS hre inner join (select hrp1.person_id    
                                                ,hre1.employee_number
                                                ,(hrp1.last_name+', '+hrp1.first_name) as fullname
                                           from dbo.xHR_PERSON hrp1
                                                ,dbo.xhr_employment hre1
                                           where hrp1.person_id = hre1.person_id
                                           AND   getdate() between hrp1.effective_start_date 
                                                            and    hrp1.effective_end_date
                                        ) hrpx on hre.supervisor_id = hrpx.person_id
                                INNER JOIN xxDirectReports AS xx ON hre.Supervisor_id = xx.Person_id
    ,dbo.xHR_PERSON     AS hrp 
WHERE hre.person_id = hrp.person_id 
AND   GETDATE() between hrp.effective_start_date and hrp.effective_end_date
AND   GETDATE() between hrp.effective_start_date and hrp.effective_end_date)
```

Comment: Sorry for asking, but: have you tried? (If yes and failed: what is the error?)

Comment: Hi Tobiasopdenbrouw, just now. i inserted "create view dbo.ReportingV as " before the "WITH xxDirecReports". 
I'll update the thread once done. Thanks..

Comment: Looking forward to the result.

Comment: I edited the script from #temp to actual table. 
I get the message 'Incorrect syntax near )' when trying to execute the above.
Also, is it possible to fetch the record that starts with , based on sample data, LFG and not with SMY?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the `WITH` has been specified (beyond the closing parenthesis), you need to select all values from the CTE:

```
select * from xxDirectReports
```

This is the actual select query that constitutes the view.

This is the complete working example, with selecting the final output of the view, and some additional `GO` statements to allow the statements to be run in a single execution within SQL Server Management Studio:

```
if not OBJECT_ID('XHR_PERSON', 'Table') is null drop table XHR_PERSON
if not OBJECT_ID('XHR_EMPLOYMENT', 'Table') is null drop table XHR_EMPLOYMENT
if not OBJECT_ID('HR_DIRECTREPORTSV', 'View') is null drop view HR_DIRECTREPORTSV

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[XHR_PERSON](
[PERSON_ID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[LAST_NAME] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
[FIRST_NAME] [varchar](100)
,EFFECTIVE_START_DATE Date
,EFFECTIVE_END_DATE Date)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[XHR_EMPLOYMENT](
[PERSON_ID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[EMPLOYEE_NUMBER] [varchar](100) NULL,
[SUPERVISOR_ID] [bigint] NULL
,EFFECTIVE_START_DATE Date
,EFFECTIVE_END_DATE Date)

insert into XHR_PERSON 
select 1, 'SMY', null, '1990-01-01','9999-12-31' UNION ALL 
select 2, 'JSB',null, '1990-01-01','9999-12-31' union all
select 3, 'LFG',null, '1990-01-01','9999-12-31' union all
select 4, 'Elmer',null, '1990-01-01','9999-12-31' union all
select 5, 'Jon',null, '1990-01-01','9999-12-31' union all
select 6, 'Anne',null, '1990-01-01','9999-12-31' union all
select 7, 'Teddy',null, '1990-01-01','9999-12-31' union all
select 8, 'Alex',null , '1990-01-01','9999-12-31'union all
select 9, 'Jeff',null, '1990-01-01','9999-12-31'
update XHR_PERSON set first_name = 'A'

insert into XHR_EMPLOYMENT
select 1, '111',null, '1990-01-01','9999-12-31' UNION ALL 
select 2, '222',1, '1990-01-01','9999-12-31' union all
select 3, '333',1, '1990-01-01','9999-12-31' union all
select 4, '444',2, '1990-01-01','9999-12-31' union all
select 5, '555',2, '1990-01-01','9999-12-31' union all
select 6, '666',4, '1990-01-01','9999-12-31' union all
select 7, '777',3, '1990-01-01','9999-12-31' union all
select 8, '888',3, '1990-01-01','9999-12-31' union all
select 9, '999',8, '1990-01-01','9999-12-31';

GO
CREATE VIEW dbo.HR_DIRECTREPORTSV as
WITH xxDirectReports (Supervisor_id, Person_id, Employee_number, Employee_name, Supervisor_Empno, Supervisor_Name, Level1)
AS
(
SELECT hre.Supervisor_id
    ,hre.Person_id
    ,hre.Employee_number
    ,hrp.last_name+', '+hrp.first_name  Employee_Name
    ,hrpx.employee_number       Supervisor_Empno
    ,hrpx.fullname          Supervisor_Name
    ,0 AS Level1
FROM dbo.xhr_employment AS hre left join (select hrp1.person_id,hre1.employee_number                                                    ,(hrp1.last_name+', '+hrp1.first_name) as fullname
                                           from dbo.xHR_PERSON hrp1
                                                ,dbo.xhr_employment hre1
                                           where hrp1.person_id = hre1.person_id
                                           AND   getdate() between hrp1.effective_start_date 
                                                            and    hrp1.effective_end_date
                                        ) hrpx on hre.supervisor_id = hrpx.person_id
    ,dbo.xHR_PERSON     AS hrp 
WHERE hre.person_id = hrp.person_id 
AND   GETDATE() between hrp.effective_start_date and hrp.effective_end_date
AND   GETDATE() between hrp.effective_start_date and hrp.effective_end_date
--AND   hrpx.person_id = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT   hre.Supervisor_id
        ,hre.Person_id
        ,hre.Employee_number
        ,hrp.last_name+', '+hrp.first_name  Employee_Name
        ,hrpx.employee_number               Supervisor_Empno
        ,hrpx.fullname                      Supervisor_Name
        ,Level1+1
FROM dbo.xhr_employment AS hre inner join (select hrp1.person_id    
                                                ,hre1.employee_number
                                                ,(hrp1.last_name+', '+hrp1.first_name) as fullname
                                           from dbo.xHR_PERSON hrp1
                                                ,dbo.xhr_employment hre1
                                           where hrp1.person_id = hre1.person_id
                                           AND   getdate() between hrp1.effective_start_date 
                                                            and    hrp1.effective_end_date
                                        ) hrpx on hre.supervisor_id = hrpx.person_id
                                INNER JOIN xxDirectReports AS xx ON hre.Supervisor_id = xx.Person_id
    ,dbo.xHR_PERSON     AS hrp 

WHERE hre.person_id = hrp.person_id 
AND   GETDATE() between hrp.effective_start_date and hrp.effective_end_date
AND   GETDATE() between hrp.effective_start_date and hrp.effective_end_date)
select * from xxDirectReports;

GO
select * from HR_DIRECTREPORTSV;
```

**Update:**

> Also, is it possible to fetch the
>   record that starts with , based on
>   sample data, LFG and not with SMY?

Yes! Although the approach varies. *I would recommend having a variable within the CTE's anchoring statement, and instead of having a view, create it as a table valued function*. However, there are a number of different ways to go about selecting hierarchical data once it's assumed hierarchical form ... one of the approaches is a **Hierarchical Path**.

To add this behaviour, add a `Path` column name to the `WITH` clause, and add the following, firstly in the anchor statement:

```
convert(nvarchar(256), RTRIM(convert(nvarchar(12), hre.PERSON_ID))) Path
```

And secondly, in the recursive statement:

```
convert(nvarchar(256), rtrim(Path) + '.' + RTRIM(convert(nvarchar(12), hre.PERSON_ID))) Path
```

Then, to select the hierarchy root (LFG) and all subordinates, simply modify the query that selects from the view to this:

```
select * from HR_DIRECTREPORTSV
where Path = '3' or Path like '3.%'
```

The results are as follows:

```
Path   Supervisor_id   Person_id   Employee_number   Employee_name   Supervisor_Empno   Supervisor_Name   Level1
3   1   3   333 LFG, A  111 SMY, A  0
3.7 3   7   777 Teddy, A    333 LFG, A  1
3.8 3   8   888 Alex, A 333 LFG, A  1
3.8.9   8   9   999 Jeff, A 888 Alex, A 2
```

Comment: Hi Rabid, 
Thanks for this one. It's the select * from xxDirectReports that creates the view. And also for the "path" you specified. That worked pretty well. 
I have another problem though, as there are duplicate rows in the output. I guess I just need to revisit my join statements.
Thanks. Appreciate all the help.

Comment: This is because your anchoring query selects all records, instead of root ones. If you wish to fix this, simply `AND` this expression: `SUPERVISOR_ID is null` into your anchor query `WHERE` clause. You'll have to modify your `Path` expression to `like '%.3.%'` to compensate for the newly restricted result set.

Comment: Hello Rabid.
That's great. I was thinking of revisiting my inner join statement of put a distinct clause. Many thanks. Regards,

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can - something like

```
CREATE VIEW [mySchema].vwItem
AS
    WITH cteItem     
    AS     
    (    
        SELECT      
        item_id     AS 'ItemID',    
        item_level    AS 'ItemLevel',     
        item_number_type  AS 'ItemNumberType',    
        CASE item_level     
            WHEN 1 THEN item_id     
            WHEN 2 THEN item_parent_id     
            WHEN 3 THEN item_grandparent_id
        ELSE item_id     
        END      AS 'ItemParent',    
        FROM     
        [mySchema].[ITEM]
    )    

    SELECT     
        child.*,    
        parent.item_id   AS 'ParentId',    
        parent.desc  AS 'ParentDescription'    
    FROM     
        cteItem child  
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [mySchema].[ITEM] parent ON     
        child.ItemParent = parent.item_id
```