# Create Table As With

Tags: sql-server, create-table

Im writing sql query and i have issue which i cannot fix.

I'm trying this:

```
CREATE TABLE a
AS
WITH cteCandidates (Miejscowosc, Ulica, NrDomu, KodPocztowy)
  AS
  (
    SELECT Miejscowosc, Ulica, NrDomu, KodPocztowy
    FROM Gimnazja
    INTERSECT
    SELECT Miejscowosc, Ulica, NrDomu, KodPocztowy
    FROM SzkolyPodstawowe
  )
 Select
  e.Lp as 'Gimnazja',
  s.Lp as 'Szkoly Podstawowe'
FROM
  Gimnazja AS e
  INNER JOIN cteCandidates AS c
    ON e.Miejscowosc = c.Miejscowosc AND e.Ulica = c.Ulica AND e.NrDomu = c.NrDomu AND e.KodPocztowy = c.KodPocztowy
  INNER JOIN SzkolyPodstawowe s
        ON s.Miejscowosc = e.Miejscowosc AND s.Ulica = e.Ulica AND s.NrDomu = e.NrDomu AND s.KodPocztowy = e.KodPocztowy
        Order By 'Gimnazja'
```

And errors which i get:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.
```

And i don't know why. I think that my query is proper but clearly not, and i don't understand why.

Comment: Is ths SQL Server, or Oracle?  It feels like you're trying to apply an Oracle style syntax (create table as) to SQL Server, which won't work.

Comment: Ofcourse. You're right. I use select into and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you want:

```
WITH cteCandidates (...)
SELECT
   e.Lp as 'Gimnazja',
   s.Lp as 'Szkoly Podstawowe'
INTO a                          -- < -- table created here
FROM
   Gimnazja AS e
   INNER JOIN ...;
```

Comment: Yes. My bad. It works. But now i wonder how can i add to this table new column like: ID, which will have numeric order of rows. It is possible?

Answer (score 2):

CREATE TABLE is used to define a table schema. The WITH keyword is used to define a CTE retrieval of data. These are two completely different operations.

If you need a table within your SQL look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx to see the syntax for defining it. You then may populate it with INSERT but that's highly unlikely to be from a CTE ( see below)

Usually with CTEs you don't need to insert the data into a table; in the statement immediately after it you can just use the data retrieved as the table has been temporarily defined and populated for you automatically.

A CTE can be used to define a VIEW - see [Create view based on hierarchy / used of CTE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403215/create-view-based-on-hierarchy-used-of-cte) for an example

Comment: Why do you need a table? Where are you calling this from? If the CTE returns what you need you can just do a simple select from the CTE after you've defined it. If you're looking for long-term storage of the cte results, do insert into table select <column names> from  cteCandidates

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to create a view? Then it'd work...