# How to create a table using "With" clause in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, with-clause

I'm attempting to create a persistent table using the WITH clause however, I'm getting an error.

For context the answer that I currently find is

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
AS 
WITH my_tables_data AS ( 
   SELECT another_table.data1 AS some_value 
   FROM another_table
) 
SELECT * 
FROM some_data;
```

However, I am getting an error

> Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 5 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an
>   xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous
>   statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

My code is

```
CREATE TABLE SalesOrdersPerYear  
WITH t1 AS (
    -- Define the CTE expression name and column list.  
    WITH Sales_CTE (SalesPersonID, BaseSalary)  
    AS  
    -- Define the CTE query.  
    (  
        SELECT SALES_PERSON.SALES_PERSON_ID, SALES_PERSON.BASE_SALARY  
        FROM SALES_PERSON  
        WHERE SALES_PERSON_ID IS NOT NULL  
    )  
    -- Define the outer query referencing the CTE name.  
    SELECT SalesPersonID, BaseSalary AS TotalSales  
    FROM Sales_CTE   
    ORDER BY SalesPersonID, BaseSalary;  
)
```

Would anyone be able to provide some guidance on this?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: This really doesn't make any sense, what do you expect this to do?

Comment: That's more of a postgresql, not sql-server

Comment: there's no `CREATE TABLE WITH CTE AS(...` in SQL Server. What do you want to do?

Comment: This looks more like it would be a *view* rather than a table.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9430333/3270427

Comment: My intent is to create a persistent table that I can access via another Select statement. Originally I was using WITH statements but they're not persistent beyond the select statement they're being implemented with. Does that help?

Comment: *How* persistent a table? If you only want it within the current scope, or for the lifetime of the current connection, you'd be looking at table variables or temp tables.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is not valid syntax for sql server. you can either create a table using `CREATE TABLE` and specifying the column names and types, or you can do a `SELECT INTO` statement including data.

Approach 1 : Create the table and then populate:

```
CREATE TABLE SalesOrdersPerYear 
( SalesPersonID int, BaseSalary float)
;

WITH Sales_CTE (SalesPersonID, BaseSalary)  
AS  
(  
    SELECT SALES_PERSON.SALES_PERSON_ID, SALES_PERSON.BASE_SALARY  
    FROM SALES_PERSON  
    WHERE SALES_PERSON_ID IS NOT NULL 
)  
insert into SalesOrdersPerYear  
SELECT SalesPersonID, BaseSalary AS TotalSales  
FROM Sales_CTE   
ORDER BY SalesPersonID, BaseSalary;
```

Approach 2 - all in one step

```
WITH Sales_CTE (SalesPersonID, BaseSalary)  
AS  
(  
    SELECT SALES_PERSON.SALES_PERSON_ID, SALES_PERSON.BASE_SALARY  
    FROM SALES_PERSON  
    WHERE SALES_PERSON_ID IS NOT NULL 
)  
select  SalesPersonID, BaseSalary AS TotalSales  
into SalesOrdersPerYear
FROM Sales_CTE   
ORDER BY SalesPersonID, BaseSalary;
```

Use approach 1 when you need to specify more about the table (primary keys, indexes, foregin keys etc.

Use approach 2 for things that are more temporary. (you would normally use a temporary table such as #SalesOrdersPerYear here).

Either way, the data is now stored in your table, and you can use it again.

Using temporary tables:

```
-- Check for existence and drop first to avoid errors if it already exists.
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#SalesOrdersPerYear') is not null
    drop table #SalesOrdersPerYear

WITH Sales_CTE (SalesPersonID, BaseSalary)  
AS  
(  
    SELECT SALES_PERSON.SALES_PERSON_ID, SALES_PERSON.BASE_SALARY  
    FROM SALES_PERSON  
    WHERE SALES_PERSON_ID IS NOT NULL 
)  
select  SalesPersonID, BaseSalary AS TotalSales  
into #SalesOrdersPerYear
FROM Sales_CTE   
ORDER BY SalesPersonID, BaseSalary;
```

You could also define it as a table variable, which is a bit of a cross between the approaches:

```
declare @SalesOrdersPerYear table
( SalesPersonID int, BaseSalary float)
;

WITH Sales_CTE (SalesPersonID, BaseSalary)  
AS  
(  
    SELECT SALES_PERSON.SALES_PERSON_ID, SALES_PERSON.BASE_SALARY  
    FROM SALES_PERSON  
    WHERE SALES_PERSON_ID IS NOT NULL 
)  
insert into @SalesOrdersPerYear  
SELECT SalesPersonID, BaseSalary AS TotalSales  
FROM Sales_CTE   
ORDER BY SalesPersonID, BaseSalary;
```

This option will only persist with this batch, and does not need dropping - just like any other variable.

Comment: Additionally, would you mind elaborating on temporary? I would still need to DELETE this "Approach 2" table yes?

Comment: You would, but the table is not stored in your database, it is stored in tempdb. You can drop it at the end of your procedure. I'll update.

Comment: It looks like table variables might be what you need - they are right at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: This is great! Many thanks for being so clear and concise with your answer. This has been extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a view using WITH and SELECT :

---

```
CREATE VIEW  SCHEMA.DEMO
AS 
WITH STAGING AS ( 
   SELECT col1 as id,col2 as name from tbl1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT col1 as id,col3 as name from tbl2
) 
SELECT distinct id,name
FROM STAGING;
```

---

Answer (score -2):

```
CREATE VIEW AS my_view
AS 
WITH my_tables_data AS ( 
   SELECT another_table.data1 AS some_value 
   FROM another_table
) 

SELECT * 
FROM some_data; 

CREATE TABLE my_table AS 
SELECT * FROM my_view;
```

Comment: Hi, please expand on *why* this code answers the question. Code snippets without context are not considered good answers.

Comment: He can create my_table, creating a view with "With clause"